# How to correctly add fetch polyfill to be used by separate js files

Tags: javascript, fetch, browserify, es6-modules, polyfills

On my website I load two separate scripts `core-bundle.js`  and `page-specific-bundle.js`. Both scripts use fetch, and, as the name suggest, each one is bundled version (I'm using gulp with browserify) of "mini app" built with ES6 modules system (I'm using babelify to transpile ES6 so browserify can work on it).

Unfortunately babel is not polyfilling fetch API. How should I correctly add fetch polyfill (https://github.com/github/fetch) so it can be available in both bundles? I'm installing it via npm. Importing it in every js file would would bloat my bundle with copied polyfill code I think.

I've thought of importing in it core-bundle.js entry file - it is added first to html file. But I don't know if that would work because of ES6 modules scope - I' not sure if polyfilling window.fetch in core-bundle.js would apply to `window.fetch` in `page-specific-bundle.js` too (taking into account that it's added **after** `core-bundle.js` in html file)?

I would be grateful if anyone could help and maybe clarify some things to me?

**Edit: Question clarification:**
The question is more like - are modifications to browser's `window` object (like replacing fetch api with polyfill) cross-module? I mean, if window object was modified in one ES6 module, does it remain modified in the next one, even if both of them are unconnected in any way? Like in my question, if I load scripts like this:

```
.... page html ...
<script src="core-bundle.js">
<script src="page-specific-bundle.js"> 
... page html ...
```

and replace window.fetch in `core-bundle.js` (I suppose that this is how polyfill works- it just replaces window.fetch) will it remain replaced in `page-specific-bundle.js` too? **And is this correct way of including polyfills?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
<script> 
  window.fetch || document.write('<script src="https://unpkg.com/whatwg-fetch@1.0.0/fetch.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, this is quite obvious one, but what about es6 import usage? They put it on github as an example. Wouldn't it work if I just imported polyfill on the first line of `core-bundle.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Check **unfetch** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/unfetch), you can use it as polyfill. It's lighter than **github/fetch** (https://github.com/github/fetch) - ~**1kB** vs **9.1kB**

usage:

```
import 'unfetch/polyfill'

// fetch is now available globally!
fetch('/foo')
  .then( response => response.text() )
  .then( data => console.log(data) )
```